# IE and FF can't complete aspx page request

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page with a gridview. The user can select parameters to filter the grid. A pass-through query is built using a string builder object and then sent to DB2.

IE and FF cannot complete the page request but Chrome always succeeds.  I create a log of the page progress and send an email when the page fails so I know where it fails. IE and FF fail at the same point every time when a certain session var gets checked. The session var exists and is initialized (not null).

Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior?  Thanks.

Comment: Post some of the failing code. And maybe parts of the request headers.

Comment: do you see any errors on the browser's console for FF/IE ?

Comment: Here is what it stops on every time: if (Session["UnitSearch"].ToString() != "") - that session var is initialized and at least contains a blank string.

Comment: I don't know what is meant by "errors on the browser's console."

Comment: "errors on the browser's console" means your browser's [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), where client side errors show up. Most browsers will show the console if you press F12 on your keyboard. But your problem appears to be server side. Please post the relevant code and any server side exceptions associated with it.

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown? Try if (Session["UnitSearch"] != null) instead.

Comment: I've always had better luck with outside connections to db2 passing strings to a function / procedure.